# How to get value from the GetExitCodeProcess

Tags: c#, winapi

What is the difference between Exitcode and GetExitcodeprocess .Please provide a sample code in C# using GetExitcodeprocess 
how can we convert this C++ code to C#

```
BOOL WINAPI GetExitCodeProcess(
  _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
  _Out_  LPDWORD lpExitCode
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetExitCodeProcess` is a Win32 function that retrieves the exit code of a process that is identified by a process handle. You can pinvoke the Win32 function if you have a raw Win32 process handle:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetExitCodeProcess(IntPtr hProcess, out uint ExitCode);
```

The managed equivalent in the .net framework is [`Process.ExitCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx).

Unless you have a particular reason to pinvoke the raw Win32 API it is preferable to use `Process.ExitCode`.

Comment: It means that the process terminated with an exit code of 0. What that means is defined by the process.

Comment: If the process is successfully completed then the return value will be 0 if not what are the values expected?

Comment: Utterly impossible for me to say. Consult the documentation of the program that you are running. The meaning of the exit code is defined by individual programs.